# Run Sweave or knitr with objects from existing R session

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

Suppose I have an object `x` in my current session:

```
x <- 1
```

How can I use this object in an Sweave or knitr document, without having to assign it explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
  print(x)
@
\end{document}
```

Reason I am asking is because I want to write an R script that imports data and then produces a report for each subject using an Sweave template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it just works.  If your Sweave file is named "temp.Rnw", just run

```
> x <- 5
> Sweave("temp.Rnw")
```

You'll have to worry about naming the resulting output properly so each report doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: Sorry but how is this related to my question?

Comment: Question must not be as clear as I thought.  Don't you want to find the objects in your R session and print them all in the Sweave document?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're looking for, but I'll try again.

Comment: Yes I just realized this myself too. I always compile through command line and for some reason thought this did not work, thanks.

Comment: A related question is how to prevent knitr/Sweave from using variables in current Environment. I might have x in RAM now, but later I clear my environment, and suddenly my .Rnw or .Rmd won't compile because I forgot to define x in it, being assured by the absence of any errors on compilation.

Answer (score 20):

I would take a slightly different approach to this, since using global variables reduces the `reproducibility` of the analysis. I use `brew` + `sweave/knitr` to achieve this. Here is a simple example.

```
# brew template: "template.brew"
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
print(<%= x %>)
@
\end{document}

# function to write report
write_report <- function(x){
  rnw_file <- sprintf('file_%s.rnw', x)
  brew::brew('template.brew', rnw_file)
  Sweave(rnw_file)
  tex_file <- sprintf('file_%s.tex', x) 
  tools::texi2pdf(tex_file, clean = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
}

# produce reports
dat <- 1:10
plyr::l_ply(dat, function(x) write_report(x))
```

Comment: Exactly. Very good point. I do not recommend using global variables outside of the document either.

Answer (score 7):

Both Sweave and `knitr` makes use of the global environment (see `globalenv()`) when evaluating R code chunks, so whatever in your global environment can be used for your document. (Strictly speaking, `knitr` uses the parent frame `parent.frame()` which is `globalenv()` in most cases)

Comment: I'm experiencing a strange problem, similar to the above, but `knitr` doesn't recognize objects, created in an `R` module, which I load via `read_chunk()`. In particular, it doesn't find objects that I'm trying to use inline. What could this mean? I did all kinds of tests, restarted environment, etc., but to no avail. Any advice? P.S. I even tried assigning an object to a variable specifically in `.GlobalEnv`. (Cross-posted from my comment to a different SO question.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option I have used in the past is to have the Sweave code open a file,

in my R session

```
write.csv(x, "tabletoberead.csv")
```

in my sweave document

```
<<label=label, echo=FALSE>>= 
datatobeused<-read.csv("tabletoberead.csv")
...more manipulations on data ....
@
```

Obviously you should include code to stop if the file can't be found.