# Printing linebreaks in HTML kable table

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When creating tables using `kable`, is there a way to generate a line break (ie `< br >`)  when string in a data.frame '`dt'` has `\n` ?

For example, here:

```
library(data.table); 
dt <- fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/prince_raw_data.csv")
dt <- dt[301:303,2:6] #take three songs only

library(knitr); library(kableExtra)
kable(dt);
# use this line to view it:   dt %>% kable %>% kable_styling()
```

[image]

This relates to [Automated nicely formated book of lyrics from data.frame using markdown, knitr and glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310488/automated-nicely-formated-book-of-lyrics-from-data-frame-using-markdown-knitr-a):

Comment: Thanks for making a reproducible example, but it is not generally recommended on Stackoverflow to use external data sources. Hope my answer helps and shows how a really basic dataframe can be made very easily :)

Answer (score 6):

As the text strings contain linebreaks in the format `\n`, you could replace all of these with the equivalent HTML tag `<br>`. I prefer using `str_replace_all` from the package `stringr` but you could also consider using [gsub](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) from base R

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(stringr)


dt <- data.frame(text = c("Here is some sample text \nHere is some sample text\n", 
                          "Here is more sample text \nAgain with a linebreak"),
                 name = c("Name 1", "Name 2"))
dt$text <- stringr::str_replace_all(dt$text, "\\n", "<br>")

knitr::kable(dt)
```
````

[image]

If you aren't compiling the file to an HTML R Markdown output, you can also use `dt %>% kable(format = "html",escape = FALSE) %>% kable_styling()` to display it. Note that `escape=FALSE` prevents the linebreaks being messed up.