# R - kableExtra - Trouble inserting linebreak in html format in a cell containing string

Tags: r, line-breaks, kableextra

I want to insert a linebreak into a cell of text but can't. In the example below, I want to insert a linebreak between the string `group 1.1` and `group1.2`

I tried to read the documentation [("Best Practice for newline in LaTeX table")](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf) but couldn't solve the problem

Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

mydf <- data.frame(
  # group = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
  row = c(1:8),
  group = c("group 1.1 \n group1.2", "group 2", "group 3", "group 4", "group 5", "group 6", "group 7", "group 8")
)

mydf %>%
# mutate_all(linebreak) %>%
kable() %>%
   kable_styling()
```

If I insert `mutate_all(linebreak) %>%` it doesn't solve the problem neither

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## pdf

I was able to get it to work for pdf by setting `kable(escape = FALSE)`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

mydf <- data.frame(
  # group = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
  row = c(1:8),
  group = c("group 1.1\ngroup1.2", "group 2", "group 3", "group 4", "group 5", "group 6", "group 7", "group 8")
)

mydf %>%
  mutate_all(linebreak) %>%
  kable("latex", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

## html

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  # group = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
  row = c(1:8),
  group = c("group 1.1<br>group1.2", "group 2", "group 3", "group 4", "group 5", "group 6", "group 7", "group 8")
)

mydf %>%
  kable("html", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

See: [Printing linebreaks in HTML kable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312934/printing-linebreaks-in-html-kable-table)

Comment: Thank you @jsta. Indeed The output is as expected when I perform `knit to pdf` however, there is no output if I do `knit to html` (and I want to copy the output to a word document). That might be another question but can you help me with this?

Comment: @ecjb html answer added