# Filling PDF forms in R?

Tags: r, forms, pdf, fdf

I am seeking a way to automate PDF form filling in R. I cannot find a package written to do this. Is there an option out there?

Alternative solutions I can think of:

1. Using R to overlay a PDF containing text onto an blank PDF template.
2. Using R to generate an FDF file that can be read by some other software or code in a different language.

All of these things seem doable in Python. However, my organization leans strongly towards R, and in the past has relied upon software devs to write C# to fill out the forms. I'm hoping to use R to skip over this step.

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396755/using-loops-with-knitr-to-produce-multiple-pdf-reports-need-a-little-help-to Creating multiple PDFs in a loop.

Comment: @zx8754 That thread seems relevant to a different problem. In my case, I don't need to loop over multiple PDF generations. Instead, I need one PDF to be generated automatically upon an API call, and that PDF has precise parameters designated by the forms built into the PDF. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[staplr](https://github.com/pridiltal/staplr) package now supports this with `get_fields` and `set_fields` functions. Note that for this to work [pdftk 
server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) must be installed and in your path

`get_fields` returns a list of fields and their types from a pdf that you can modify

`set_fields` allows you to fill form according to your modifications. See below code for an example

```
pdfFile = system.file('testForm.pdf',package = 'staplr')

fields = get_fields(pdfFile)
# You'll get a list of fields that the pdf contains 
# along with some additional information about the fields.

# You make modifications in any of the fields by
fields$TextField1$value = 'this is text'

# and apply the changes you have made in a new file
set_fields(pdfFile, 'newFile.pdf', fields)
```

**Note:** Currently github version of staplr has fixes that are yet to make into CRAN that affect staplr's ability to write in non-english alphabets. For best experience you may want to install it by doing

```
devtools::install_github('pridiltal/staplr')
```

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction to installing the pdftk server on Windows and hooking it up to R?

Comment: You just need to download it and place it somewhere in your PATH, or add it to your PATH. You can change your path from Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> path. This is for windows 8/10.

Comment: Hey @OganM I tried to use the package that you suggested, staplr, but I am getting some errors. I posted a question in Stackoverflow. Would you please give your suggestions?  Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69921405/find-keys-and-values-in-a-pdf-with-r