# Knitr:spin - how to add text without manually adding #' every line?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

My understanding is that `knitr:spin` allows me to work on my plain, vanilla, regular ol' good R script, while keeping the ability to generate a full document that understands markdown syntax. (see https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/)

Indeed, the `rmarkdown` feature in `Rstudio`, while super neat, is actually really a hassle because

- I need to duplicate my code and break it in chunks which is super boring + inefficient as it is hard to keep track of code changes.
- On top of that `rmarkdown` cannot read my current workspace. This is somehow surprising but it is what it is.

All in all this is **very** constraining... See here for a related discussion [Is there a way to knitr markdown straight out of your workspace using RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155182/is-there-a-way-to-knitr-markdown-straight-out-of-your-workspace-using-rstudio).

As discussed here (http://deanattali.com/2015/03/24/knitrs-best-hidden-gem-spin/), `spin` seems to be the solution.

Indeed, `knitr:spin` syntax looks like the following:

```
#' This is a special R script which can be used to generate a report. You can
#' write normal text in roxygen comments.
#'
#' First we set up some options (you do not have to do this):

#+ setup, include=FALSE
library(knitr)
```

in a regular workspace!

**BUT** note how each line of text is preceded by `#'`.

My problem here is that it is also very inefficient to add `#'` after each single line of text. Is there a way to do so automatically?

Say I select a whole chunk of text and rstudio adds this `#'` every row? Maybe in the same spirit as commenting a whole chunk of code lines?

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: What about replacing every hash with a hash and an apostrophe in a selected chunk of code?

Comment: thanks dude but I just wanna write my text without adding anything manually. that completely defeats the purpose of helping to write a scientific document...

Comment: Are you talking about comment text inside a code chunk or regular text outside of a code chunk? Can you post a sample of your full rmarkdown document?

Comment: I mean regular text outside of a code chunk. Something like "in this paper we do this this and this and oh by the way this is the output when we do this" and then boom I show the output of my code chunk

Comment: For regular text outside of a chunk, just type regular text. No hash marks are needed.

Comment: I cannot get it to work `library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

this is a test this is a test

data <- data_frame(c('one', 'two', 'trree'))

data`

Comment: I cannot compile the short R code above. What am I missing again? thanks!

Comment: Open a new `rmarkdown` document in RStudio, which includes a sample document. Note how R code is set off in separate chunks. For inline R code, that is, R code within a sentence, let's say that you've created a value `x` earlier in a code chunk and you want to use it in a sentence. Then you can type this (without the double quotes): "And now we can see that \`x\` is equal to \`r x\`". All the basic info on using R markdown can be found [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html).

Comment: It sounds like he wants to use `knitr::spin` and not write an rmd.

Comment: that is exacly that. sorry for the confusion I am updating my question

Comment: If you need the objects in your script, but hate typing the roxygen comment, why not just `source` your code in the beginning of an `rmd`?  This way you don't have to worry about matching environments of `knitr` and your code, and can reference any objects constructed by your code.

Comment: HI @JakeKaupp do you mean using `source` allows me to 1) load my data once and for all and 2) create some charts, compile, change some stuff, compile again, add some text, re-compile WITHOUT loading the whole data again???

Comment: Yes. Or you can just put that code in a rmd chunk, and have it run and have access to everything.

Comment: i am confused. If I put the thing in a code chunk, how can I compile my document without rstudio needing to reload everything? according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155182/is-there-a-way-to-knitr-markdown-straight-out-of-your-workspace-using-rstudio rmarkdown needs to run the whole stuff again. sorry if I dont get your point again

Comment: what I want to do is to generate my html/pdf/whatever many times as I write it, but without needing to run the whole code every time.

Comment: Really, the easiest way to regenerate results quickly, without running long running parts, is to use the caching feature of chunks in knitr. Look it up, it will make re-runs of full documents take much less time. This applies for either `spin` or `knit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RStudio v 1.1.28, starting a line with `#'` causes the next line to start with `#'` when I hit enter in a `*.R` file on my machine (Ubuntu Linux 16.04LTS).

So as long as you start a text chunk with it, it will continue. But for previously existing R scripts, it looks like you would have to use `find -> replace`, or write a function to modify the required file, this worked for me in a very simple test.

```
comment_replace <- function(in_file, out_file = in_file){
  in_text <- scan(file = in_file, what = character(), sep = "\n")
  out_text <- gsub("^# ", "#' ", in_text)
  cat(out_text, sep = "\n", file = out_file)
}
```

I would note, that this function does **not** check for preexisting `#'`, you would want to build that in. I modified it so that it shouldn't replace them too much by adding a space in the regular expression.

Comment: I would also note that if you **start** with using Rmd, the whole thing is much easier, and you can use `Ctrl+alt+p` to run all previous chunks, run all chunks to get similar behavior as `rmarkdown::render`.

Comment: thanks! one question that I still have is the following. say my first chunk of code loads all the data I need. Can I comment that code afterwards so that when I `render` my document Rstudio only uses the objects in memory?

Comment: you can comment that code, or use `eval=FALSE`, so it won't get re-run on next render.

Answer (score 0):

With an RMarkdown document, you would write something like this:

````
As you can see I have some fancy code below, and text right here.

```{r setup}
# R code here
library(ggplot2)
```

And I have more text here...
````

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/jeromyanglim/2716336) offers a quick introduction to RMarkdown and `knitr`'s features. I think you don't entirely understand what RMarkdown really is, it's a markdown document with R sprinkled in between, not (as you said) an R script with markdown sprinkled in between.

---

Edit: For those who are downvoting, please read the comments below this... OP didn't specify he was using `spin` earlier.

Comment: yeah thanks but that is the problem. Rmarkdown does not allow to use objects in memory so I have to run the whole thing at once. I dont want Rmarkdown, I want to use knitr.

Comment: @Noobie Oh, that makes much more sense. Try https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/

Comment: yes thanks, I am talking about `spin` here. you are right https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/

Comment: @Noobie Hmmm, I don't think there's a way to automate `#'`, besides find and replace. Which text-editor are you using? There might be some sort way to write an extension for it.

Comment: im just using Rstudio my friend

Comment: @Noobie Then it looks like find-and-replace is the only option :(

Comment: awww that's horrible

Comment: if you use `rmarkdown::render()`, and `cache=TRUE`, you can easily combine knitr and in memory objects, and then just re-render. Maybe you should expand on your use case in another SO post, that may get you better suggestions.