# Generating knitr reports

Tags: r, knitr

I'm pretty new to `knitr`, but I've written a script that generates a report for a county. One of the first lines in the first code chunk is `display_county <- "King"`, and it queries a database to make all sorts of nice things about King County. Now I want to create reports for every county in my state. The only line in the script that needs be changed is the definition of `display_county`.

I know the `brew` packages is set up for stuff like this, and I know there's overlap between `brew` and `knitr`, but I don't know what I should be using.

[This answer using Brew and Sweave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437769/903061) would work with minor modifications, but is there a nice `knitr` way to bypass `brew`?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't make a vector of the counties and then iterate over it?

Comment: @BryanHanson Not at all, and that's just what I did using `brew` as in Ramnath's linked answer. But it *feels* like something I ought to be able to do just in `knitr`.

Comment: Have you tried it in `knitr`?  If it works in `R` via interactive or script, I don't see why you can't do it with `knitr` too.  I've never used `brew` but have used `knitr` and `sweave` extensively, and I think it should be possible.

Comment: The key is the nature of content inside your loop. If it is mainly programmatically generated content, knitr works great. But when there is text markup, brew + knitr is cleaner. In your case, you can use child templates to achieve it using just knitr.

Comment: See this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959312/create-parametric-r-markdown-documentation/14959759#14959759). It shows loop using child templates. In either case, you need to create an extra file, and `brew` + `knitr` leads to a more compact solution.

Comment: for this specific application, `knit_expand()` should work well; see example 075 in https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples

Comment: I might be making a controversial point here, but my strong belief is that `brew` + `knit` provides much cleaner solutions compared to any of the other approaches, especially when templates are involved. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/5569a8d6dc20f6353485) to compare with the `knit_expand` approach. I would welcome a discussion on pros and cons here.

Comment: You might also try `pander` like described in http://rapporter.github.com/pander/#brew-to-pandoc - please check out the `short-code-long-report.brew` example.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you are going to use the same Rnw file for each county, so only the variable `display_county` will be different for each county.  I would first make the call to the database to get all the names of counties and store them in a vector (say... `myCounties`).  After that, your reports can be generated with a script containing the following:

```
for(dc in myCounties)  {
  knit2pdf(input='county_report.Rnw', output=paste0(dc, '_county_report.pdf'))
}
```

To handle errors more effectively, you can also wrap the knit2pdf call on a tryCatch statement:

```
for(dc in myCounties)  {
  tryCatch(knit2pdf(input='county_report.Rnw', output=paste0(dc, '_county_report.pdf')))
}
```

Comment: `c` is a pretty terrible name for the index of a loop since it is also a pretty important function in R.  You might consider renaming the index.