# Can knit2pdf use the global environment?

Tags: r, knitr

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437393/903061), @Yihui said that `knitr` uses the global environment. This confused me--my experience had been that it doesn't. I never really use `knit` though, I usually go straight to PDF.

In a little experiment, it seems that `knit` does use the global environment (or whatever environment you specify using the `envir` argument), but that `knit2pdf` doesn't.

Minimal example: global_test.Rnw file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
    print(x)
@
\end{document}
```

R Script:

```
x <- "Hello World"
knit(input="global_test.Rnw")
# Works as expected, could now call tools::texi2pdf to generate pdf.

knit2pdf(input="global_test.Rnw")
# Doesn't
```

The latter generates PDF file that won't display and gives a warning:

```
running command '"C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\texi2dvi.exe" --quiet --pdf
"global.pdf"  -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1
```

I tried passing an environment to `knit2pdf` (`envir = globalenv()`) hoping it would be `...` passed on, I just get an unused argument error.

Generally, I know that referencing the global environment is poor form, but is there a way to do it with `knit2pdf`, or to pass an environment explicitly, or am I better off using `brew` and `sprintf` as in [@Ramnath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437769/903061) to the same question above?

In my use case, I don't think `tools::texi2pdf` is useful because I need to compile with XeLaTeX, which `knit2pdf` handles effortlessly.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `envir` parameter in `knit2pdf` explicitly?

Comment: Yeah, I just get an unused argument error.

Comment: Have you tried it without referencing a global variable? I get exactly the same error when I try to use `knit2pdf()`, when the one line of R code is `print("Hello World")` (i.e. when there's no explicit reference to a global variable)... I'm on a Windows XP box, using R-devel, and `knitr_1.1`, with a MikTeX distro under the hood.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks for pointing that out! It all seems to be a problem with the `output` argument to `knit2pdf`, when that is gone everything else works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problems with the examples in the question seem to have nothing to do with environments. Everything will compile correctly and without warnings if the `output` argument is left off of `knit2pdf`.

For reference, I was using knitr 1.1 on R 2.15.3 on Windows 7. I'll let Yihui know as it appears to be a bug in `knit2pdf` (which calls `tools::texi2pdf`, which doesn't accept an output file path).

**UPDATE:** The problem has been fixed in the development version of `knitr`, [available here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr).

It's also worth noting that the `Compile PDF` button in **RStudio** *does not* use your current environment, so if you want to have access to global variables and you are using RStudio, make an explicit call to the appropriate `knit` function rather than relying on the shortcut. In fact, it doesn't use `knit2pdf` directly, rather it calls `rmarkdown::render`.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue! The real story is, `knitr` 1.1 does not have the `envir` argument; the development version of `knitr` added it, but later removed the `output` argument. Now the latest development version has both arguments, and `knit2pdf()` should work fine now.

Comment: I am using Rstudio with R markdown. Does this apply to markdown documents also? I am using source() to run a script inside a cached chunk. I want to use the objects computed in that script in later chunks, but those  objects don't seem to be available to later chunks. Can you clarify what I need to do?

Comment: @statistician_in_training Objects defined in one chunk should definitely be available in later chunks, no matter how you're compiling. If you're having problems with that, create a minimal example and post it as a question.

Comment: I have created a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222380/)  with a minimal example, about using cached chunks with sourced scripts and accessing R objects in later chunks.

Comment: @Yihui. I tried the above code with R_3.0.1, knitr_1.5, Emacs/ESS on Windows7 but I still get message "... had status 1". When I remove output part the pdf was produced.

Comment: Thanks to posting [multiple-pdf-reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396755/using-loops-with-knitr-to-produce-multiple-pdf-reports-need-a-little-help-to?rq=1) I could solve my problem. If I change  `output = 'globaltest.pdf'` to `output = 'globaltest.tex'` the pdf-file will be produced.

Comment: @giordano In your case (perhaps also in most cases), you do not need to specify the `output` argument at all.