# Sweave in RStudio cannot find objects loaded in global environment

Tags: r, rstudio, sweave

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434371/run-sweave-or-knitr-with-objects-from-existing-r-session) I thought I could use R objects loaded in the global environment straight away in `.Rnw` documents and compile them directly to PDF in RStudio. But unfortunately that does not work for me...

I would like to make a `summary` of a `data.frame` that undoubtably is already loaded in my global environment.

Evaluating `summary(JLLdata)` in the console produces the correct output. However, when I try to include `summary(JLLdata)` in my `.Rnw` file, I get the error `(chunk 1) Object 'JLLdata' not found`.

Here my `.Rnw` Syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<JLLdata>>=
summary(JLLdata)
@

\end{document}
```

And here a screenshot from R Studio (you can see that `JLLdata` is in the global environment and the Compile PDF error)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code from the Sweave .Rnw document is run in a separate R session, so it does not have access to objects you've loaded or created in the console. You have to explicitly load the data in a Sweave code chunk in order for it to be accessible when you call `summary`.

Comment: Thx @Thomas, you were right. Including  `load(file = "/path/globalenvironmnetsaved.RData")` does the job..It is a bit of an annoying solution though, since my `.RData` is 200MB big and  hence compiling the PDF takes a while...

Comment: Consider using knitr instead, which gives a caching option that greatly reduces compilation times.

Comment: Or just use `Sweave()` from the command line, since R itself has the flexibility that GUI-button convenience inevitably takes away. Perhaps write a little utility function to streamline the process, putting it in your .Rprofile or a  personal package for easy loading. Something like: `sweave2pdf <- function(file) {
    texfile <- Sweave(file);
    tools::texi2pdf(texfile)
}`